# A doubt in the proof "Period three implies chaos"

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I'm working on the article by Lee and Yorke "Period three implies Chaos" and despite trying and understanding the proof, I can't understand how we can ensure that the set of subsequences defined on the proof of T2 Theorem 1 it is not empty. I suppose that if I undertand this, I will understand also the same in 2.2.

[PDF File](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/144b/e7a4c12d40f45aca578292d353d74d00e3ab.pdf)